# Node.js script const variables in SCREAMING_SNAKE_CASE or camelCase

Tags: coding-style, coding-standards, node.js, clean-code

**TL/DR:** When requiring another script in Node.js and defining it as a const should the variable name still be in camelCase like it was usual with var or should it instead be in SCREAMING_SNAKE_CASE as is more usual for a const?

```
const someVariable = require('...js');
```

vs

```
const SOME_VARIABLE = require('...js');
```

---

**Longer version:** In Node.js another script is usually imported using

```
var someScript = require('path/to/someScript.js');
```

With ES6 being available in Node.js such a var could instead be declared as a const (or in some cases as a let if it's ever redefined).

Now as we're working on defining a style guide for our development we came to the conclusion in other languages like Typescript (Angular 2) that whenever we declare a const we write the variable name in SCREAMING_SNAKE_CASE like

```
const SOME_CONSTANT_VARIABLE = '123';
```

Now we would conclude that this means that in Node.js we should define our script variables like

```
const SOME_SCRIPT = require('path/to/someScript.js');
```

As you're usually using those script variables a lot in Node.js code can become quite difficult to read. Also I couldn't see a lot of examples of other people doing it similarly and instead often use it like

```
const someScript = ...;
```

so still writing the variable name in camelCase.

My question is as a  What is the preferred / best practice way of writing those variable names using ES6 const?

Comment: I've never heard it called SCREAMING_SNAKE_CASE before but 1) that's hilarious and 2) that gives me great mental images.

Comment: “Constant” doesn't necessarily mean a const variable, but a value that will be unchanged for all runs of the program – basically named literals. Often the value of constants is known at design time. Reserving UPPERCASE variables for these kinds of constants might be a good idea. After all, nearly all `var`s could usually be `const`.

Comment: The 'SCREAMING_SNAKE_CASE' had traditionally been used only for pre-processor macro identifiers in languages such as C, where the pre-processor is a *pre-compilation* step which operates before the compiler itself starts running.  A pre-processor step essentially re-writes source code before feeding into the compiler.  Pre-processor macros do not follow the same "rules" as the rest of the language syntax; all-uppercase identifiers put a clear distinction so that programmers can instantly recognise the difference between compiled statements and pre-compiiled statements.

Comment: Fabulous question. We are currently facing the very same problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not really declaring a variable, but what other languages call an alias.

Example in Python:

```
import numpy as np
```

Example in C#:

```
using Project = PC.MyCompany.Project;
```

For your case, from [the official node.js module API documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html):

```
const square = require('./square.js');
const mySquare = square(2);
console.log(`The area of my square is ${mySquare.area()}`);
```

Or

```
console.log('main starting');
const a = require('./a.js');
const b = require('./b.js');
console.log('in main, a.done=%j, b.done=%j', a.done, b.done);
```

Different languages use different conventions. The official node.js API documentation uses camelCase, you should use camelCase.

Comment: Thank you for the quick and expressive answer. That's kind of what I thought but I haven't had any written proof for it. Didn't notice the official documentation was already updated to use const.